# Can't add public key for use with Graph API

Tags: azure

I currently have an application set up in my Azure Registered Apps, and I'm unable to add my public key under 'Certificates & Secrets'. I tried generating a key like [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cryptography/Generate_a_keypair_using_OpenSSL), and the resulting public (or private, for that matter) key (`.pem`) was unable to be added to the app. I'm using this key for some work with JWTs, so I thought that maybe I'd need a slightly different format, so I tried making a pair like [this](https://gist.github.com/ygotthilf/baa58da5c3dd1f69fae9) as well. Still no luck.

The only way I was able to get some form of credential added to the app was actually creating & self-signing a `.crt` with the previously generated keypair, that is the only case where Azure has not complained about me adding a credential.

Trying to add anything else, even the public `.pem`, which it says **IS** a supported filetype, gives this error:

`Failed to add certificate. Error detail: Upload a certificate (public key) with one of the following file types: .cer, .pem, .crt [8jpdkHO8jJ6PaePjw7NvbJ]`

Having the `.crt` uploaded simply won't suffice, the fingerprint on my private key that I'm using with `jwt.decode()` aren't matching up with what is registered on Azure, causing errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use stackoverflow often, so not sure on etiquette and whether re-posting after your answer has been deleted is ok. either way, I've fixed it up and added the actual steps, rather than just linking to them.

Following the certificate generation instructions [here](https://arsenvlad.medium.com/certificate-based-auth-with-azure-service-principals-from-linux-command-line-a440c4599cae) allowed me to upload the public key.

The steps are as follows:

Generate Certificate

```
openssl req -x509 -days 3650 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
```

Grab Thumbprint

```
echo $(openssl x509 -in cert.pem -fingerprint -noout) | sed ‘s/SHA1 Fingerprint=//g’ | sed ‘s/://g’ | xxd -r -ps | base64
```

You should then have a certificate azure will allow you to upload, as well as the thumbprint to use in any requests.